# Enable or disable dropdowns based on selected value in other dropdown using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select, disabled-input

I want to remove an attribute from an element when I pick the `Student` option from a drop-down list. If I choose `Teacher`, or `Staff`, the course and year level will disable, but if I choose `Student`, it will enable *thanks for your  response*.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Type:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="type" id="type" required>
            <option></option>
            <option>Student</option>
            <option>Teacher</option>
            <option>Staff</option>
            <option></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Course Type:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="course" id="course" required>
            <option></option>
            <option>BSIT</option>
            <option>BSCS</option>
            <option>BSHRM</option>
            <option>BSBM</option>
            <option>BSTM</option>
            <option>COE</option>
            <option></option>                                   
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Year Level:</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select name="year_level" id="year_level">
            <option> </option>
            <option>First Year</option>
            <option>Second Year</option>
            <option>Third Year</option>
            <option>Fourth Year</option>    
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is the JavaScript:**

```
<script>    
    document.getElementById('type').onchange = function () {  
        var obj = document.getElementById('course').setAttribute('disabled',this.value=='Student');

        document.getElementById('course').setAttribute('disabled',this.value=='Teacher');
        document.getElementById('year_level').setAttribute('disabled',this.value=='Teacher');

        obj.setAttribute('disabled');
        obj.removeAttribute('disabled');
    }    
</script>
```

**Drop-down:** [drop-down print-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lqlf.png).

**Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/dzpr46d4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To again enable the dropdowns, you need to remove the `disabled` attribute, using below code:

```
document.getElementById('course').removeAttribute('disabled');
```

I have [**edited your JSFIDDLE DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/o7kkt4md/6/). Here is the code:

```
     document.getElementById('type').onchange = function () {
     alert("selected value = "+this.value);
     if(this.value == "Student")
     {
            document.getElementById('course').removeAttribute('disabled');
document.getElementById('year_level').removeAttribute('disabled');

     }
     else
     {
            document.getElementById('course').setAttribute('disabled', true);
                    document.getElementById('year_level').setAttribute('disabled', true);

     }
      }
```

Comment: you did great!! Thank you so much my friend!!! that 5 hours I spent for this code, you solve it  like 1minute thank you!

Comment: It says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." sorry I'm just a new here just created this account 30mins ago, I will up you for sure thank you